# How to convert HTML with mathjax into Latex using Pandoc?

Tags: html, latex, mathjax, pandoc

I have some HTML documents with MathJax equations, and I want to convert them to Latex, and then to pdf. I'd like to use Pandoc.

However, Pandoc replaces `$` with `\$` and it replaces `\` in formulas with `\textbackslash{}`.

Is it possible to get Pandoc to pass MathJax formulas literally from HTML to Latex?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the latest version of pandoc (1.12.2), you can do this:

```
pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash -t latex
```

Much nicer!  If you don't want to convert math delimited by `\(` and `\)`, just do

```
pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars -t latex
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not an easy task.  Here's a solution that should work, provided you only use `$` and `$$` as math delimiters, and assuming your document doesn't contain any other uses of `$`.  (If you can't assume that, you can try adjusting the perl regex in what follows.)

Step 1:  Install the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform//), if you don't have it already, and 'cabal install pandoc' to get the pandoc library.  (If you installed pandoc with the binary installer, you only have the executable, not the Haskell library.)

Step 2:  Now write a small Haskell script -- we'll call it fixmath.hs:

```
import Text.Pandoc

main = toJsonFilter fixmath

fixmath :: Block -> Block
fixmath = bottomUp fixmathBlock . bottomUp fixmathInline

fixmathInline :: Inline -> Inline
fixmathInline (RawInline "html" ('<':'!':'-':'-':'M':'A':'T':'H':xs)) =
  RawInline "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs
fixmathInline x = x

fixmathBlock :: Block -> Block
fixmathBlock (RawBlock "html" ('<':'!':'-':'-':'M':'A':'T':'H':xs)) =
  RawBlock "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs
fixmathBlock x = x
```

Compile this:

```
ghc --make fixmath.hs
```

This will give you an executable `fixmath`.  Now, assuming your input file is `input.html`, the following command should convert it to latex with the math intact, putting the result in `output.html`:

```
cat input.html | \
perl -0pe 's/(\$\$?[^\$]+\$\$?)/\<!--MATH$1-->/gm' | \
pandoc -s --parse-raw -f html -t json | \
./fixmath | \
pandoc -f json -t latex -s > output.tex
```

The first part is a perl one-liner that puts your math bits in special HTML comments marked "MATH".  The second part parses the HTML into a JSON representation of the Pandoc data structure corresponding to the document. Then `fixmath` transforms this structure, changing the special HTML comments into raw LaTeX blocks and inlines.  (See [Scripting with pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) for an explanation.)  Finally we convert from JSON back to LaTeX.

Comment: Is there some way to make the executable `fixmath` work with `pandoc-ruby`?

Comment: And how should the Haskell script be written to not convert math which is delimited by `\(\)`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492982/convert-html-and-inline-mathjax-math-to-latex-with-pandoc-ruby

Comment: See my latest answer.