# export mathjax to latex

Tags: latex, mathjax

Is there some tool that would turn an HTML with mathjax into a valid LaTeX document? I undernstand that mathjax is already LaTeX, but if that is mixed with text, then simply saving the text representation of an HTML document is not going to work. E.g., the underscore should be turned into a backslash + _, when it is in the text section, while it should be left alone, if it is in a math environment. My question is, whether there is a way to do this automatically. I would prefer a javascript solution, but if that is absolutely not possible, I could live with a tool (e.g., python) that I can call from the command line.

Thanks,

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc) might help.

Comment: Thanks! I have already seen that, but I think that solution is a bit convoluted: there is perl, haskel, and pandoc involved.

Comment: @v923z - Pandoc is a Haskell library - you need something to parse the HTML.  John  MacFarlane has written a simpler alternative that should work with little adaptation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014717/convert-html-mathjax-to-markdown-with-pandoc/16022396#16022396

Comment: @charles-stewart pandoc is also an application: http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Since I wanted to convert to LaTeX only, I ended up with a small script that strips the formulae from the HTML document. I see that pandoc is quite capable, though.