# Convert html mathjax to markdown with pandoc

Tags: html, mathjax, pandoc

I have some html files including mathjax commands.
I would like to translate it into php extra markdown using pandoc.

The problem is that pandoc add "\" before all math commands. For example
\begin{equation}
\$
x\^2
etc

Do you know how to avoid that with pandoc ?
I think a related question is this one : [How to convert HTML with mathjax into latex using pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a short Haskell program unescape.hs:

```
-- Disable backslash escaping of special characters when writing strings to markdown.
import Text.Pandoc

main = toJsonFilter unescape
  where unescape (Str xs) = RawInline "markdown" xs
        unescape x        = x
```

Now compile with `ghc --make unescape.hs`.  And use with

```
pandoc -f html -t json | ./unescape | pandoc -f json -t markdown
```

This will disable escaping of special characters (like `$`) in markdown output.

A simpler approach might be to pipe pandoc's normal markdown output through sed:

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown | sed -e 's/\\\([$^_*]\)/\1/g'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The simple regex seems to work ok. However, if one is using markdown together with mathjax, escaping the asterix can be useful for example with \begin{align\*}