# Convert HTML and inline Mathjax math to LaTeX with pandoc ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, haskell, latex, pandoc

I'm building a Rails app and I'm looking for a way to convert database entries with html and inline MathJax math (TeX) to LaTeX for pdf creation.

I found similar questions like mine:

- [Convert html mathjax to markdown with pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014717/convert-html-mathjax-to-markdown-with-pandoc)
- [How to convert HTML with mathjax into latex using pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc)

and I see two options here:

1. Create a Haskell executable which leaves stuff like `\(y=f(x)\)` alone when converting html to LaTeX
2. Write a ruby method which does the following things:

   - Take the `string` and split it into an `array` with a regex (`string.split(regex)`)
   - loop through the created `array` and if content matches `regex` convert the parts to LaTeX which do not include inline math with `PandocRuby.html(string).to_latex`
   - concatenate everything back together (`array.join`)

I would prefer the ruby method solution because I'm hosting my application on Heroku and I don't like to checkin binaries into git.
*Note: the `pandoc` binary is implemented this way http://www.petekeen.net/introduction-to-heroku-buildpacks)*

So my question is: what should the `regex` look like to split the `string` by `\(math\)`.

*E.g. `string` can look like this:* `text \(y=f(x) \iff \log_{10}(b)\) and \(a+b=c\) text`

And for the sake of completeness, how should the Haskell script be written to leave `\(math\)` alone when converting to LaTeX and the ruby method is not a possible solution?

Comment: I'm not sure but don't think that the standard Ruby regex engine has any recursion support. In which case matching arbitrary balanced parenthesis becomes a lot more tricky.

Comment: @Qtax something like `string.split(/(\\\(.*?\\\))/).each_slice(2).map { |a| [PandocRuby.html(a[0]).to_latex, PandocRuby.convert(a[1].to_s, {f: "html+tex_math_single_backslash", to: :latex})] }.join` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the very latest version of pandoc (1.12.2).  Then you can do

```
pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash -t latex
```

Comment: Thanks @john-macfarlane, this almost works perfectly. The only issue is that `$$y=f(x)$$` is converted to `$$y=f(x)$\\$\n` instead of `$$y=f(x)$$\n`. Any idea why?