# Unable to compile Haskell program ("Couldn't match" errors)

Tags: haskell, pandoc, haskell-platform

I'm trying to implement the Haskell solution by John MacFarlane [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc), which should allow me to convert HTML files with MathJax (latex) input to .tex while preserving the math. The script is:

```
import Text.Pandoc

main = toJsonFilter fixmath

fixmath :: Block -> Block
fixmath = bottomUp fixmathBlock . bottomUp fixmathInline

fixmathInline :: Inline -> Inline
fixmathInline (RawInline "html" ('<':'!':'-':'-':'M':'A':'T':'H':xs)) =
  RawInline "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs
fixmathInline x = x

fixmathBlock :: Block -> Block
fixmathBlock (RawBlock "html" ('<':'!':'-':'-':'M':'A':'T':'H':xs)) =
  RawBlock "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs
fixmathBlock x = x
```

I installed the 64-bit OSX version of Haskell, and also gave the command `cabal install pandoc` to get the pandoc functions. However, upon executing

```
ghc --make fixmath.hs
```

I get the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( fixmath.hs, fixmath.o )

fixmath.hs:9:26:
    Couldn't match expected type `Format' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the pattern: "html"
    In the pattern:
      RawInline "html"
                ('<' : '!' : '-' : '-' : 'M' : 'A' : 'T' : 'H' : xs)
    In an equation for `fixmathInline':
        fixmathInline
          (RawInline "html"
                     ('<' : '!' : '-' : '-' : 'M' : 'A' : 'T' : 'H' : xs))
          = RawInline "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs

fixmath.hs:10:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `Format' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `RawInline', namely `"tex"'
    In the expression: RawInline "tex"
    In the expression: RawInline "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs

fixmath.hs:14:24:
    Couldn't match expected type `Format' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the pattern: "html"
    In the pattern:
      RawBlock "html"
               ('<' : '!' : '-' : '-' : 'M' : 'A' : 'T' : 'H' : xs)
    In an equation for `fixmathBlock':
        fixmathBlock
          (RawBlock "html"
                    ('<' : '!' : '-' : '-' : 'M' : 'A' : 'T' : 'H' : xs))
          = RawBlock "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs

fixmath.hs:15:12:
    Couldn't match expected type `Format' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `RawBlock', namely `"tex"'
    In the expression: RawBlock "tex"
    In the expression: RawBlock "tex" $ take (length xs - 3) xs
```

What's gone wrong and what can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions of pandoc changed the type of the "format" for RawBlock and RawInline.  If you replace `"html"` and `"tex"` with `(Format "html")` and `(Format "tex")`, you should be okay.  (Assuming there aren't other problems besides the one the compiler flagged.)

Comment: Thanks for this. It now only returns one (different) error. I get the following (sorry for formatting): _fixmath.hs:3:8: No instance for (ToJsonFilter (Block -> Block)) arising from a use of toJsonFilter Possible fix:add an instance declaration for (ToJsonFilter (Block -> Block)) In the expression: toJsonFilter fixmath In an equation for main: main = toJsonFilter fixmath_

Comment: This is due to another change in pandoc since I posted that script.  Try using `toJSONFilter` instead of `toJsonFilter`.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, with the small addition of `import Text.Pandoc.JSON` at the top of the code. I'm not sure why I had to declare the second import command, but the single `import Text.Pandoc` was still giving me errors.