# dealing with equation environments in pandoc.

Tags: pandoc, mathjax

I have HTML text with embedded `mathjax` and I want to convert it to LaTeX. [I can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc) `pandoc` with the options `tex_math_dollars` and `tex_math_single_backslash` and it does a pretty good job of conversion.

However it can't handle environments. pandoc text escapes all the internal content, not realizing that it should be passed through verbatim to the LaTeX processor.

For example if I have a fragment

```
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
```

in a file `test.html`, and I run the command

```
pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash -t latex test.html
```

I get the output

```
\textbackslash{}begin\{equation\} a\^{}2 + b\^{}2 = c\^{}2
\textbackslash{}end\{equation\}
```

I even tried using ``` to demarcate code blocks as in the pandoc user manual, but that had no effect.

Comment: This looks very much borderline for us: isn't it essentially a Pandoc issue?

Comment: That's possible. I wasn't entirely sure. It might be reasonable to migrate it to SO

Comment: @Suresh I'm not pandoc expert but **1** I think the code block syntax applies to markdown not to html **2** try different output formats to isolate if it is a problem with missing reader options or missing writer options **3** check the pandoc filters, especially the part in the docs that says "The latter form may be useful for debugging filters"