# MD with Latex to HTML with MathJax with Pandoc

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, mathjax

Somewhat similar to [How to convert HTML with mathjax into latex using pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc) but in some sense, the opposite.

If I'm using Pandoc to create MD files with LaTeX, or even just MD files, how can I use Pandoc to convert these to HTML with the correct `\(\)`, `\[\]` tags for math?

Comment: [Math in Pandoc Markdown](http://pandoc.org/README.html#math) is actually wrapped in dollar signs, not `\(\)` tags.

Comment: @mb21 Yes, I understand that, the issue is when converting to HTML with mathjax I need these tags, not the dollar signs.

Answer (score 19):

Following discussion [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1847), I am able to convert `test.md` (containing LaTeX code) to `test.html` successfully.

```
pandoc --toc --standalone --mathjax -f markdown -t html test.md -o test.html
```

The doc on `--mathjax`can be found [here](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--mathjax):

> Use MathJax to display embedded TeX math in HTML output. TeX math will be put between (...) (for inline math) or [...] (for display math) and wrapped in  tags with class math. Then the MathJax JavaScript will render it. The URL should point to the MathJax.js load script. If a URL is not provided, a link to the Cloudflare CDN will be inserted.

The option `--standalone` is important, without which the LaTeX code can not be rendered correctly.

PS. wrap inline equation like `$INLINE EQUATION$` and wrap display equation like `$$DISPLAY EQUATION$$`.

Comment: You sir, are a great gentleman and scholar. This has so much upgraded the level of output.

Answer (score 4):

You want to convert from markdown to html with mathjax support?

```
pandoc --mathjax input.md -o output.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows as platform, the following `.CMD` snippet should do the conversion:

```
set PATH=%ProgramFiles%\pandoc;%PATH%
set CDN=http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML

set IN=%~s1

if [%2]==[] (
  set OUT=%~sdp1%~n1.html
) else (
  set OUT=%~s2
)

echo Converting markdown to html ...
pandoc.exe -s --mathjax=%CDN% --from=markdown+pipe_tables --to=html --output="%OUT%" %IN%
```

Consult the [pandoc help](http://pandoc.org/README.html) to tune the commandline parameters.

Comment: I'm in a unix environment, but I may be able to decipher this. Thanks, I'll update after I see how this goes.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [mathjax-node-page](https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-page/) (from html to html) and they are truly self-contained. From my Makefile:

```
# Convert
pandoc aperture_synthesis.md -t html --self-contained -s --standalone --mathjax -o aperture_synthesis.html
cp aperture_synthesis.html out1.html
# Independentize from MathJax CDN
$$HOME/Program/MathJax/node_modules/mathjax-node-page/bin/mjpage --output CommonHTML < out1.html > aperture_synthesis.html
```