# Use PANDOC to convert a MathJax HTML to PDF

Tags: pdf, pandoc, mathjax

I sucessfully converted a MathJax HTML file to a PDF, however the pdf did not came with equations rendered.

[pdfimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocp5F.png)

I used the command `pandoc mathjax.html --pdf-engine=xelatex -o example13.pdf`

How can i get the pdf with the equation?

Comment: how do i add this? 

        `pandoc -from html mathjax.html --pdf-engine=xelatex -o example13.pdf``

would it be like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert HTML with mathjax into latex using pandoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338049/how-to-convert-html-with-mathjax-into-latex-using-pandoc)

Comment: so: `pandoc -f html+tex_math_dollars+tex_math_single_backslash input.html -o output.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex`

Comment: only the first line got rendered? also how do i remove the title? and page nubering? :( 

 \( \frac{1}{a} is not rendering

Comment: i seen that topic but i couldn't use that example to figure out

Comment: see http://pandoc.org/getting-started.html and http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Comment: also manual and getting started wont help